# Issues accessing C# class from another .cs file

Tags: c#, forms

I'm creating a login form that, when the authentication is completed successfully, inserts 3 parameters (userID, user and displayName) on the following class:

userSession.cs

```
namespace Summaries
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Stores the user information sent by the server
    /// </summary>
    class UserSession
    {
        public int userID { get; set; }
        public string user { get; set; }
        public string displayName { get; set; }
    }
}
```

When I'm on the login form, I can write/read from the class, but when I try to read on my main.cs file it returns null.

main.cs

```
private void main_Shown(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    UserSession session = new UserSession();
    sessionLabel.Text += session.displayName;
}
```

It is probably just a newbie mistake, but can you show me how to access the values or, if this approach is not ideal/possible, a way to store and access the values between forms?

**EDIT**: I've already tried different approaches to "initialize" it. I also tried `UserSession session;` but got a "Use of unassigned local variable 'session'"

**My workaround**: Instead of using a class from another file to try and store the user information, I decided to pass the information to the other form at the moment of the call:

login.cs

```
private void loginBTN_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        serverResponse response;
        userSession session;

        string username = usernameBox.Text;
        string password = passwordBox.Text;
        string jsonResponse = LoginValidation(username, password);
        response = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<serverResponse>(jsonResponse);

        if (response.status)
        {
            session = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<userSession>(jsonResponse);
            main mainForm = new main(session.userID, session.user, session.displayName);
            this.Hide();
            mainForm.Show();
        }
        else
        {
            ...
        }
}

    private class userSession
    {
          public int userID { get; set; }
          public string user { get; set; }
          public string displayName { get; set; }
    }

    private class serverResponse
    {
           public bool status { get; set; }
           public string errors { get; set; }
    }
```

main.cs

```
private int userID;
private string user;
private string displayName;

/// <summary>
/// Main function from  the dashboard form.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="id">The user id retrived from the database</param>
/// <param name="username">The username retrived from the database (login name)</param>
/// <param name="display">The name to be displayed that was retrived from the database</param>
public main(int id, string username, string display)
{
    InitializeComponent();
    userID = id;
    user = username;
    displayName = display;
}
```

Using this approach, I can get the values to my main.cs file but with the downside that I have to pass them whenever I want to open/show a different form.

Comment: `new UserSession();` creates a new instance - one where you haven't set any values so they all have the defaults

Comment: Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question. Then [edit] your question to include the source code you have as a [mcve], which can be compiled and tested by others.

Comment: @UnholySheep I was trying to initialize it that way because using UserSession session; gives a "Use of unassigned local variable 'session'" error

Comment: You have to store the "original" `UserSession` somewhere where your "main.cs" can access it then. Where exactly that is is a code architecture decision you have to make

Comment: Make `UserSession` public. There could be issues with accessing :)

Comment: @Pawel as @UnholySheep said, with the `new UserSession();` I'm creating a new instance. My issue now is to find ways to store the user info and be able to access it through another form

Comment: You are asking the wrong question. The question you need to ask is "How classes and objects work in OO languages?" Search for that online please.

Answer (score 3):

There are two things to look for in your question:

In `UserSession` you could add explicit `public` or `private` and a constructor - a special method used to "construct" instances of a class.

```
public class UserSession
{
    public int UserID { get; set; }
    public string User { get; set; }
    public string DisplayName { get; set; }

    public UserSession(int id, string user, string displayName) 
    {
         UserID = id;
         User = user;
         DisplayName = displayName;
    }
}
```

Explicitly specifing `private` (default) or `public` is good for maintainability and is kind of a standard in C#.

And when you want `UserSession` object call it like this:

```
var user = new UserSession(id, user, displayName);
```

where *id*, *user* and *displayName* are other variables or constants.

Effect is the same as with assigning properties by hand after calling `new UserSession()` (without any parameters), but in most cases using constructor is considered better practice.

In your case however

```
private void main_Shown(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    UserSession session = new UserSession(**id**, **name**, **displayName**);
    sessionLabel.Text += session.displayName;
}
```

You need to provide those variables or constants that are added to constructor to that method. If your application is a WebForms, then you should have it somewhere and you need to provide it e.g in `EventArgs`. You can do the same if you are in desktop environment.

However, in desktop environment you have another viable option that will work fine **provided that you have only one user**. You can create field in a class that owns the method from above. And assign fields of `UserSession` objects as you go.

You could also (in one user scenario) make `UserSession` a static class with public properties and **no constructor** and then you would again assign to properties of the class as soon as you have the data about the user. You wouldn't have to create any instance nor filed then, because static fields are accessible by their class name (and there is only one instance of this class program-wide, hence only one user).

```
.... before ....
UserSession.DisplayName = "user";
... then ...
private void main_Shown(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    sessionLabel.Text += UserSession.DisplayName;    
}
```

This is not a recommended option, but I include it for completeness.

Answer (score 1):

```
new UserSession();
```

Creates a new instance and for all the properties in the class have the default values of each. Therefore, you should assign values for each property after instantiation.

```
private void main_Shown(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    UserSession session = new UserSession();
    session.userID = "<user id>";
    session.user = "<user>";
    session.displayName = "<displayName>";
    sessionLabel.Text += session.displayName;
}
```

Comment: But using that code implies that I have to write the user information myself. I'm trying to use classes or other forms of store the user information to be accessible on all project's forms.

Comment: If you are not using any API calls or any database calls to retrieve user data, You can use a static class to store user data. Or else you can use Sessions if your solution is a web based approach.

Answer (score -2):

In c#, you can define any class as static class, so it's public properties could be accessed by another class directly.

Cheers...

[Static classes and static class members](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/static-classes-and-static-class-members)